# APOC trigger get nodes for removed relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I want to create an apoc trigger that will trigger when a relationship is removed. The trigger needs to find the nodes `m` and `n` that the deleted relationship was connecting. Below is what I have, but `MATCH (m)-[deletedRel]->(n)` does not find any matches. What is the correct way to find the two nodes that were connected by a removed relationship?

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('myTrigger',
"UNWIND $deletedRelationships as deletedRel
WITH apoc.trigger.toRelationship(deletedRel, $removedRelationshipProperties) AS deletedRel
WITH deletedRel WHERE apoc.rel.type(deletedRel) = 'MY_REL_TYPE'
MATCH (m)-[deletedRel]->(n)
WITH deletedRel, m, n
CREATE (r:Report {myId: id(deletedRel), type: apoc.rel.type(deletedRel)})" ,
{phase:'before'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `startNode` and `endNode` functions, like this:

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('myTrigger',
"UNWIND $deletedRelationships as deletedRel
WITH apoc.trigger.toRelationship(deletedRel, $removedRelationshipProperties) AS deletedRel
WITH deletedRel WHERE apoc.rel.type(deletedRel) = 'MY_REL_TYPE'
WITH deletedRel, apoc.rel.startNode(deletedRel) AS m, apoc.rel.endNode(deletedRel) AS n
CREATE (r:Report {myId: id(deletedRel), type: apoc.rel.type(deletedRel)})" ,
{phase:'before'})
```

Comment: That works, just need to add `apoc.rel.` before `startNode` and `endNode`.